# Select records by date specified for every record individually

Tags: mysql

I have situation where I want to select records by date, but that date FOR RECORD SELECTION is different for every record, because I need to add `days_gap` to it.

So I need something like that:

```
`select from user_options where email_sent_at < time_now - days_gap`
```

Is it possible?

DB structure:
`user_options`

```
user_id | email_sent_at | days_gap
1       | 2016-07-27    | 2
2       | 2016-07-24    | 2
3       | 2016-07-22    | 5
4       | 2016-07-21    | 3
```

Comment: select from user_options where email_sent_at < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL days_gap DAY

Comment: @Bert make an answer out of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To substract a number of days from a date, you can use MySQL's INTERVAL, which accepts a column as an argument for the amount of days.

```
create table user_options
(   user_id int auto_increment primary key,
    email_sent_at date not null,
    days_gap int not null
);
insert user_options values
(1, '2016-07-27', 2),
(2, '2016-07-24', 2),
(3, '2016-07-22', 5),
(4, '2016-07-21', 3);

select * from user_options where email_sent_at < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL days_gap DAY;
+---------+---------------+----------+
| user_id | email_sent_at | days_gap |
+---------+---------------+----------+
|       2 | 2016-07-24    |        2 |
|       4 | 2016-07-21    |        3 |
+---------+---------------+----------+
```